# Error when starting mongodb Abort Trap: 6

Tags: mongodb

When trying to start mongodb with command mongod, this is the message I get. I'm totally new to this and haven't a clue what it means.

```
mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEE+0x39) [0x10bcb85f9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_110abruptQuitEi+0xBD) [0x10bcb7edd]
 libsystem_platform.dylib(_sigtramp+0x1A) [0x7fffce616b3a]
 ??? [0xc886049f]
 libsystem_c.dylib(abort+0x81) [0x7fffce49b420]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15invariantFailedEPKcS1_j+0x2E6) [0x10bcade46]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD9_newOpCtxEPNS_6ClientEj+0x152) [0x10a86df32]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14ServiceContext20makeOperationContextEPNS_6ClientE+0x43) [0x10bbaa613]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo6Client20makeOperationContextEv+0x18) [0x10bba6768]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_112shutdownTaskERKNS_16ShutdownTaskArgsE+0xB9) [0x10a654a79]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8shutdownENS_8ExitCodeERKNS_16ShutdownTaskArgsE+0x320) [0x10bcb38b0]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15NamespaceStringC2ENS_10StringDataE+0x0) [0x10a6555d0]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_+0x2E9) [0x10a654169]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x10a653009]
 libdyld.dylib(start+0x1) [0x7fffce407235]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: "invariant failed" is a generic type of error.  Did the mongod log any additional messages that expand on that?

Comment: en: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating
So I must need to stop running mongodb?